# Please help me to change the colour of all "female" gender elements

Tags: javascript, html, class

I have to use the class that add red colour to female gender

```
//let users = [
  {
    "_id": "5f5f1f33a26fa00de3c6f2a3",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,603.84",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 20,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "AVENETRO",
    "address": "135 Gerry Street, Ola, Oklahoma, 2403",
    "registered": "2019-04-16T09:56:44 -03:00",
    "greeting": "Hello, Velez Heath! You have 1 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "apple"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5f5f1f33bd48c4b7c4efe2636",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$2,566.21",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 38,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "gender": "female",
    "address": "330 Evans Street, Johnsonburg, New Hampshire, 1390",
    "registered": "2016-10-04T11:44:00 -03:00",
    "greeting": "Hello, Gardner Stark! You have 4 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
  }]
```

```
var tr= "<tr>[enter image description here][1]" + Object.keys(users[0]).map(function(key){
  return "<td>"+key+"</td>"
}).join('') + "</tr>";

users
.sort(function(a,b){
   return a.age - b.age
 })
.forEach(function(element){
    td = Object.keys(element)
.map(function(key, index){
        return "<td>"+element[key]+"</td>"
    }).join('') + "</td>";
 tr += "<tr>"+td+"</tr>";
if(element.gender=="female")
{
//here 
}
});
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

table.innerHTML=tr;
```

Comment: For me, this is hard to read. Please fix the indentation

Answer (score 1):

Add style into the HTML element, and for simplicity, we can use [back tick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for string interpolation with [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
`<td style="${(element.gender === 'female') ? 'color: red;' : ''}" >${ element[key] }</td>`
```

If the current `element.gender` is female, the output will `<td style="color: red;"></td>` and the style will be empty if it is male.

So in your code, it will be something like this

```
users.sort(function(a,b){
   return a.age - b.age
}).forEach(function(element){
   td = Object.keys(element).map(function(key, index){
            return `<td style="${(element.gender === 'female') ? 'color: red' : ''}" >${ element[key] }</td>`;
        }).join('') + "</td>";
   tr += "<tr>"+td+"</tr>";
});
```